# UITableview Reuse Identifier

Tags: objective-c

In UITableViewcell I have created a collection view and when i selected one cell of collection view some functionality is there..that is behaving weird.This is happened because I am using reuse identifier in IB same as my nib name.

Comment: if i use some different reuse identifier(other than nib name) then this functionality is behaving correctly.

Comment: can you show your tried code?

Comment: i just want to ask, can i use my nib file name as reuse identifier if in uitable view cell there is a collection view is used.